# Bind android apk with image

Tags: java, android, sdk

Is it possible to bind an .apk app to a .jpeg image? I mean when the image is opened it will run the .apk app 
I found the androRat binder that I can embed two apks in one package, when run the package the two apps will run.
So could it be possible to bind apk with image?

Answer (score 0):

It could be but that would be known as a hack.

So no, at least officially, there is no way to do this for obvious security reasons.

Comment: in windows it would be possible but the output package will be .exe so its still needs a permission to lunch it , I want to know if it is possible to make the same in android ?

Answer (score 0):

Use of Command shell and assembly language might do the task for you. meanwhile you can simply combine any file with image using the copy command by providing the names of two files as input source and single image name to be the output file.

Comment: please give me an example for that